# data is different when printing vs asssigning as a variable

Tags: python, json

I am looping through a json array grabbing 2 data keys, displayName and currency. If i print the data it prints the correct data but when I assign it as a variable the data is different than what is printed.

```
import json
from firebotpy import firebot



def write(data):
    f = open('data.txt', 'a')
    f.write(f"{data}"'\n')

with open('data.json', encoding= 'utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    user_data = data['userData']
    x = user_data.keys()
    for user in x:
        try:
            print(user_data[user]['displayName'])
            print(user_data[user]['currency'])
            user = user_data[user]['displayName']
            value = user_data[user]['currency']
            print(user)
            print(value)
        except:
            pass
```

now when I print the data it prints the correct data but when i assign it to a variable it does not. What am I doing wrong?

TERMINAL when printing the daya, first two lines of code

```
30
gggymm
151
arturo_544
40
megan3308
37
ryunjin_98
241
xxpainlovexx
129
ヤン얀
18
leominakata
16
jairock08
11
antiheroe00
6
```

TERMINAL when assinging the data to a variable and printing it

```
2
spawned55
2
spawned56
2
spawned57
2
spawned58
2
spawned59
2
spawned60
2
spawned61
2
spawned62
2
spawned63
2
spawned64
2
spawned65
2
spawned66
2
spawned67
2
spawned68
2
spawned69
2
```

Comment: Did you really mean to replace the value of *user* (after the two *print* calls)? Perhaps you explain why you might want to do that. Without being able to see your input data it's hard to discern your intention

Comment: you are overwritting the value of user? you are using the variable `user` in the loop `for user in x:` but then assigning a value over that inside the loop `user = user_data[user]['displayName']` then you useing that new assigned user value to look up user_data

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't entirely clear from the sample inputs and outputs, but I assume you're asking why the entries in the array aren't changing even after assigning a new value to `user`. Your code implies you want `user` to become just the display name key of the `user` dict, so here's my explanation:

---

The `user` variable in the for loop stores a value. This might sound obvious, but there's a catch in the simplicity: The variable stores **the value of the array element**, not the element itself.

So when you assign a value to the variable `user`, it won't update the array itself. It just updates the value of the variable `user` for the remainder of the loop body, and in the next iteration the variable `user` is changed to the value of the next array element.

The solution would be:

```py
user_data[user] = user_data[user]['displayName']
```

Which will change the array element itself.

Comment: Ya that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @DadTheGamer no problemo! Also, if the answer solved your question in its entirety, don't forget to mark it as correct - it helps anyone in the future with a similar doubt :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how your data is structured, I cant really do too much to help.

But from what I understand, this might help solve the problem.

```py
data = {'userData': [{'displayName': 'Test1', 'currency': 50}, {'displayName': 'Test2', 'currency': 65}]}

for x in data['userData']:
    for key, value in x.items():
        try:
            # use key and value variables how ever you like here
            print(key)
            print(value)
        except:
            pass
```

or

```py
for x in data['userData']:
    name = x.get('displayName')
    currency = x.get('currency')

    print(name)
    print(currency)
```